# Omega 4: manually installing a subtheme

Tags: theming

Just learning Omega 3 and 4 is out so I'm switching to try it out, but.. how does one install a subtheme manually? My drush is whacked and I already running multiple installs so I just want to do it manually.

However, copying the "default" folder to the sites/all/themes/ folder... there is no info file... so I duped the one in Omega, changed the name and it shows in the Appearance menu. However, the name isn't correct and I've gone through the few files to see what to change to my themes name but there was only one file.

So, I enabled one, it enables, but then when I click "Settings" next to that theme, I get the WSOD.

Seems not to be the same process as in D6 or even Omega 3. Anyone installed a subtheme of Omega 4 yet manually?

Comment: I answered this, with specific steps, here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171957/creating-omega-sub-theme-manually/171985#171985

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go the omega theme folder omega\starterkits select : default or extended folder and copy in site/all/themes . 
change folder name default or extended to your subtheme name for example "alex".

go to your theme folder finde the extended.starterkit.inc or default.starterkit.inc and change to your theme name in my case is: alex.info

open alex.info and change name and description of your subtheme.

Comment: when I click setting url in omega subtheme then overall site went to dead

Answer (score 1):

Use drush it will solve your problem
cd to *.../sites/all/themes*

run

```
drush omega-wizard
```

and follow the steps

Comment: was this ever resolved? I had a problem with installing Omega 4 sub theme on windows :   http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/103594/omega-4-sub-theme-problem-with-file-get-contentsmake-libraries-failed-to-open

Answer (score 0):

run `drush omega osup [themename]`

Answer (score 0):

1. This method used for Omega 3 and 4 which I advise.

> ```
> 1) Install Omega theme
> 2) Download drush7.x from [here][1]
>    http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/#windows-zip-package
> 3) Unzip the file some where safe (I am using wampserver so I have placed in into C:\wamp\bin\windrush) 
> 4) Add the drush to your windows command so you can call drush from commandline.
>    Go to => start windows/ system / Advanced system settings/ Environment Variables / Select Path from system variables / Edit / add the drush path to here e.g. ;C:\wamp\bin\windrush; don't forget to use ";" to separate the paths.
> 5) now open you command line and enter
>
>    drush omega-subtheme name-of-sub-theme
> ```

2. You should be having a new sub-theme in drupalsites/all/themes/name-of-sub-theme

But if you are using Omega 3 the other option would be simply install "Omega Tools" module to create subtheme (Bear in mind Omega 4.x should NOT be used with Omega Tools and Delta)