# Omega 4 Sub-Theme problem with file_get_contents(make.libraries) failed to open stream

Tags: drush, theming

[image: error]

when creating an omega 4 sub-theme using drush 6 on windows 7 and xampp and drupal 7, see attached pic,'file_get_contents(libraries.make) : failed to open stream : no such file or directory make.utilities.inc:471  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug of [Omega](https://www.drupal.org/project/omega) theme, so you should follow Drupal issue queue for details: [Invalid or empty make file: libraries.make](https://www.drupal.org/node/2200473).

As workaround, you may to navigate to subtheme's folder (e.g. fifth_avenue subtheme dir) and run:

```
drush make libraries.make --no-core --contrib-destination=.
```