# Creating Omega sub theme manually

Tags: drush, theming

I'm trying to create a functioning sub theme of Omega 4.4. I've worked  with Drush before with it, but the site is on a host that I'm not administrator of. I've tried the [Drush Webservice module](https://www.drupal.org/project/drushweb) but not succeeded in executing the Omega Wizard. In short, the Omega Wizard may be extremely helpful, but I can't get it to work.

Next, I've tried to manually create a sub theme using the [instructions here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INKX1baST3U). However, the results of this is a theme catalogue in the Themes-folder, but the theme not showing up in Drupal. Perhaps I'm using the wrong instructions for the wrong version of Omega?

Anyhow, does anyone have instructions for how to install an Omega 4.4 sub theme manually for Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1):

This documents manually copying the default starterkit subtheme in Omega 4.4. The instructions are similar for both "dusty" and "default" starter kits. Note that the "default" theme has libsass, and has less files then "dusty."

- **Dusty:** the original omega front-end set up, which is becoming increasingly outdated.
- **Default:** a more contemporary subtheme, front-end development wise. This is the better option.

Note: since I use a simple, one-word theme name in this example I can replace THEME-placeholders with one value. If you wish to have a more complex subtheme name, consider this array from the drush omega subtheme function:

```
'/{{ THEME }}/' => $machine_name,
'/{{ THEME NAME }}/' => $name,
'/{{ THEME SANITIZED }}/' => str_replace('_', '-', $machine_name),
'/{{ THEME CAMELCASE }}/' => $camel,
'/{{ THEME CAMELCASE LOWER }}/' => lcfirst($camel),
```

Prerequisite: Your theme's name. I'm using "mytheme" Substitute mytheme with your theme name.

1. Copy `themes/omega/omega/starterkits/default` (or `dusty`) to `themes/mytheme`
2. Copy `default.starterkit.inc` to `mytheme/mytheme.info`
3. Changes to `mytheme.info`

   - Change the `name` value to `'mytheme'`
   - Insert `base theme = omega` to line 3
   - Change the theme file names from `{{  THEME SANITIZED }}` to `mytheme`
     For example - from:
     `stylesheets[all][] = css/{{ THEME SANITIZED }}.reset.css`
     To:
     `stylesheets[all][] = css/mytheme.reset.css`
   - Change the scripts name to css/mytheme.behaviors.js
   - Add regions info:
     ; ========================================
     ; Regions
     ; ========================================
     regions[branding] = Branding
     regions[header] = Header
     regions[navigation] = Navigation
     regions[highlighted] = Highlighted
     regions[help] = Help
     regions[content] = Content
     regions[sidebar_first] = First Sidebar
     regions[sidebar_second] = Second Sidebar
     regions[footer] = Footer
4. Update theme name in files:

   - package.json: `{{ THEME }}` to `mytheme`
   - template.php: `{{ theme name }}` to `mytheme`
   - theme-settings.php: `{{ THEME }}` and `{{ theme name }}` to `mytheme`
   - preprocess/page.preprocess.inc: `{{ THEME }}` to `mytheme`
   - process/page.process.inc: `{{ THEME }}` to `mytheme`
   - sass/README.md `{{ THEME SANITIZED }}` to `mytheme`
   - The following renames are in `dusty` only:

     - `.ruby-gemset`
     - `bower.json`
     - `libraries.make`
5. Rename files as necessary:

   - Rename css files to `css/mytheme.reset.css` (default subtheme only) and `css/mytheme.styles.css`
   - Rename scss files to `sass/mytheme.reset.scss` (default subtheme only) and `sass/mytheme.styles.scss`
   - The following file-renames are in `dusty` only:

     - Rename css files to `css/mytheme.hacks.css`, `css/mytheme.no-query.css` and `css/mytheme.normalize.css`
     - Rename scss files to `sass/mytheme.hacks.css`, `sass/mytheme.no-query.scss` and `sass/mytheme.normalize.scss`

And there it is:[image: screenshot of the newly activated theme]

I've created a github of that shows the comparitive starterkit to wizard-created subthemes. Using this link, you can see all the necessary modifications you'll need to make, for dusty [here](https://github.com/kyleskrinak/omega-4.4-manually/compare/dusty...master) or for default, [here](https://github.com/kyleskrinak/omega-4.4-manually/compare/default-original...default-wizard)

I've updated this document out of pure curiosity. If I were in your situation, however, I would simply run the omega-wizard on my local dev environment, and push the theme to my server.